# Django REST Framework ValidationError along with params

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The ValidationError raised by Django REST Framework doesn't include params like how Django's Validation error includes it. The REST Framework catches Django's Validation Error and raises it's Validation error which doesn't include params.

Is there any way to keep params in the REST Framework ValidationError which are raised by Django's Validation Error?